# Using user entry to copy paste range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am working on a small task where I need to extract selective data from one workbook to another, and plot the graphs. Now, I have the following code which copies the data from source sheet and pastes into the destination sheet. But the issue is, the selection of data will be different each time i.e., it may be A2:A9 and D2:D9 this time, but next time it could be A2:A100 and D2:D100. Is there anyway I can setup a control where a user can input the beginning and end range of each column to select the data?

Many thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Workbooks("PressureTest.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A9,D2:D9").Copy _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    Columns.AutoFit

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started.

LastRow:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ActiveSheet


'Ctrl + Shift + End
  LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

LastColumn:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastColumn As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Using UsedRange
  sht.UsedRange 'Refresh UsedRange
  LastColumn = sht.UsedRange.Columns(sht.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
```

All details are available here.

https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Comment: Thank you for replying. Perhaps I did not make my requirements clear. I cannot use last row functions since the data I need picking will always be from somewhere between the whole range i.e., when I say A2:A100, then A100 is not the last row. Similarly, it may be A50:A150 sometime. So I was wondering if the user could enter the value of first and last cell on the spreadsheet and VBA gets the data between specified range.